# How to send a MemoryStream Text Plain by Mail Message C#

Tags: c#, email, attachment, memorystream

I'm trying to attach a log file to my mail but I don't receive anything. This is my example. What I'm doing wrong? I can see the my file log.txt is created and placed in the path but it's not sending the email if I try to attach this part.

```
private void AssignAttachment(MailMessage msg, DataTable dt, StreamReader streamreader)
{
    FileStream fs = (FileStream)streamreader.BaseStream;
    string file = "c:\\temp\\log.txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //Testing. Col 0 = string results
            sw.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i][0]);
        }
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        ms.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
    }

    //MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    //msg is well-configured email. Sends emails if I don't attach anything
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms,file, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
}
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors? What are they?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Attachment` takes in a `Stream` as the first argument, you should be able to specify your `FileStream` instead of the `MemoryStream`. This will remove the need for the intermediary stream and will allow for a streaming upload instead of loading the entire file into memory.

When you open your file for reading after it is written, simply pass that stream into the `Attachment` constructor.